# Inverting a Hankel matrix with factorial element growth

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, hankel-matrices

A problem in theoretical physics has led me to consider a Hankel matrix $H$ whose elements are given by $H_{ij} = (i+j-1)^{i+j-1}$, where $i, j = \left[1, N\right]$ for any $N$ you like. I'm curious to know if there is any hope of inverting this matrix, ideally in such a way that we can learn properties of the inverse in the large $N$ limit.

Of course, we can make progress numerically for sufficiently small $N$, but these matrix elements grow rapidly and it isn't long before machine precision is an issue. It seems that an analytical insight is necessary, but I'm not familiar with results for Hankel/Toeplitz matrices and have no idea if a solution for this problem is within reach. Any literature recommendations for this subject are welcome, in addition to any examples which can provide intuition for how the Hankel matrix structure can help in finding the inverse.

Comment: Is there any interpretation, prehaps physical, of the sequence $n^n$ $n\ge 1$  ? Do you know if this sequence is positive definite, or equivalently $H_N$ is positive definite matrix for any $N$ ?

Comment: It's certainly true that $H$ is positive definite, every matrix element is bounded below by 1. There is a physical origin for the factorial-like scaling, but I don't think our understanding of that is particularly helpful for this problem.

Comment: Positive definite means that all eigenvalues are real and positive. Equivalently all principal minors are positive. Sometimes the property can be derived from interpretation of the terms, as inner products of some vectors for example.

Comment: Oh geez I always flub that definition. Sorry. Anyway I went and checked properly and indeed it is a positive definite matrix for arbitrary $N$.

Comment: How do you know that it is positive definite ? Usually it is not easy.

Comment: I thought I had a proof but looking again there is a bound that I need to prove but don't know how. Instead I've checked that the principal minors are all positive numerically for N=100, and they grow faster than exponentially. I doubt that breaks down; so I don't have a general proof but I suspect these are positive definite. If we assume that is always the case how much does that help with my original question?